# How to add many Polylines to canvas element?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, polyline

I have something like this: `canvasGraph.Children.Add(new Polyline(){Points = new PointCollection((x1, y1), (x2, y2))});` but it does not work and I don`t know how to deal with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing your point collection the wrong way:

```
canvasGraph.Children.Add(new Polyline(){
  Points = new PointCollection(
    new List<Point> {
      new Point(x1, y1), 
      new Point(x2, y2)})});
```